Qualcom Snapdragon X Elite Arm64 Desktop support. When to expect?
Qualcom Snapdragon X Elite Arm64 Desktop support.
When can we expect this to happen?
Do you yet have a time frame?

armhf (32-bit) and arm64 (64-bit) are already supported.

This question is similar to: How full is the Ubuntu ARM port (repositories)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu (probably) won't support it until the kernel does.
There's also the issue of multiple devicetrees.
You can cobble together a working installer if you are willing to be adventurous.
My effort gave me a working desktop, it complains about a bunch of things like gpu firmware and I haven't gotten sound working yet. Keep in mind that Qualcomm / Codelinaro are still working on completing their kernel work for the platform.
I believe I used a 6.11-rc3 fork from one of the codelinaro folks that's working on the Snapdragon X, manually specified it in the installers GRUB along with my device's DTB file.
linux   (fs-with-kernel)/kernel-image ...

devicetree (fs-with-dtb)/your-model.dtb

(Disclaimer: I don't know what the f I'm doing.)

I would be interested in finding out more about how you did this. I have migrated all my Windows VMs to Snapdragon so am only keeping x64 intel ones for the Ubuntu servers now due to Ubuntu not yet supporting this (and only bare metal installs) where the installer just hangs. When I Google codelinaro I just find a repository last updated a year ago so some more pointers would be appreciated if possible. Not bothered about sound. I'm hoping official support might come soon.
